# There's no Maven generators in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

[image]

when i try to make new 'maven' project, there is no 'maven' menu but only maven archetype. Actually i checked that maven is installed in PC safely through cmd. Plus, I can't find maven in plugins marketplace. Let me know how to make new maven project.

Answer (score 2):

Please use "New project" and select needed build system on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

It should appear under New project Option.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEb8s.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).